# What does "incoming" and "outgoing" traffic mean?

Tags: networking, firewall

I've seen many resources explaining **how** to set up a server's firewall to allow incoming and outgoing traffic on HTTP standard ports (`80` and `443`), but I can't figure out **why** I would need either of them. Do I need to unblock **both** for a "regular" web site to work? For file uploads to work? Are there situations where it would be advisable to unblock one and leave the other blocked?

Sorry if that's a basic question, but I couldn't find it explained anywhere (also I'm not a native english speaker). I know in a "regular" web site the client is always the one who initiates a request, so I'm assuming a web server must accept incoming traffic on those ports, and my common sense tells me the server is allowed to send a response without unblocking anything else (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have two types of rules). Is that correct?

But what is an outgoing web (service) traffic, and what would be its use? AFAIK if the server wanted to initiate a connection with another machine, the specific port that matters is the one in the other end (i.e. the **destination port** would be `80`), on its end any free port could be used (the **source port** would be random). I can open HTTP requests from my server (using `wget` for instance) without unblocking anything. So I'm assuming my concepts of "incoming" and "outgoing" are wrong somehow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Incoming" and "outgoing" are from the perspective of the machine in question.

"Incoming" refers to packets which originate elsewhere and arrive at the machine, while "outgoing" refers to packets which originate at the machine and arrive elsewhere.

If you refer to your web server, it mostly accepts incoming connections to its web service, and only occasionally (or maybe never) makes outgoing connections.

If you refer to your web client, it mostly makes outgoing connections to other services, and only occasionally (or maybe never) accepts incoming connections.

Clear as mud now?

Comment: I would add tha In order to send a response to your client you need to allow outgoing traffic for established connections. So whenever a client establishes a connection to your port 80 your server can talk back to any port of the client.

Comment: Quite correct. Though any stateful firewall should handle this automatically.

Comment: So, my web server should unblock incoming connections on ports `80` and `433`, does not need to worry about outgoing connections on those ports, but need to allow outgoing connection in the dynamic/ephemeral port range, is that right? And I'm still a bit confused with the outgoing thing: if a web client tries to connect to a site, the destination port would be `80`, but the source port could be anyone. Which port would a firewall **in that machine** consider when deciding to block/unblock?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Now you're veering into the theoretical. We prefer practical questions here. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, didn't mean to digress, it seems I misunderstood @Hex's comment and I wanted a clarification. From my understanding now, outgoing rules refer to the **destination** port - so if the client originated the request on its port `X` (its source port) the server must accept outgoing traffic to `X` to be able to send a response (automatically - as you said - or not, but it must allow). Did I get it right now? (if so, the answer to my last comment would be: the destination port)

Comment: Considering that you have limited knowledge of firewalls and traffic I would recommend you to use a firewall builder script. UFW is a good start. The project's webpage is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW , have a look at it and you will gain a basic understanding of firewalls and traffic management. If you still need help I'll try to give a detailed clarification to your question.

Comment: does incoming traffic also include traffic coming in during an outgoing connection? is the term incoming traffic the same as the term inbound traffic?

Answer (score 9):

In your case you only have to let incoming requests to port 80.

When a connection is established, the firewall will automatically let packets out back to the client's port. You don't need to create rules for that because the firewall knows.

Comment: This doesn't answer his whole question, but yes, if he's using a stateful firewall, only 80 and 443 are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Without any context as to what the particular text you read means when they refer to "outgoing web service" traffic, I'll take the simplest approach in my answer:

1. You have a firewall at the ingress/egress of your network.
2. The firewall comes in a fully locked down state and allows NO inbound or outbound traffic.
3. In order for your internal clients to browse external web sites you need to configure an "outbound web service" rule that allows them to connect to said external web sites.

In the simplest terms the rule would read something like this:

ANY internal host to ANY external host where the destination = TCP Port 80 then ALLOW.

Comment: The expression "outgoing web service traffic" came from [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-11-how-to-block-or-open-httpweb-service.html). In my particular case, I'm trying to set up the firewall in a server instance (IBM cloud). The default install came with most things blocked (I could run Apache but not access it from outside), and I'd like to know the miminal things I should unblock to be able to serve pages, receive file uploads (from the client's browser), etc. And I couldn't tell if that particular piece applied to my case or not - since it only tells how, not why.